# How to run IIS, before the WCF service running?

Tags: wcf, iis

How to **run IIS** from web.config, before the **WCF Service** running?

Comment: Please provide more information, what error are you getting or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @lat3ncy. There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:7177/wcf/SharedService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. After I activate IIS Service(W3SVC), the error does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution running the IIS service at the beginning of the program, like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        StartIISService();
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }

    private static void StartIISService()
    {
        ServiceController controller = new ServiceController();
        controller.ServiceName = "W3SVC";
        controller.MachineName = SystemInformation.ComputerName;
        if (controller.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            controller.Start();
        controller.Dispose();
    }
```